# Can't start firefox with Hudson

Tags: hudson, webdriver, vnc-server

I'm trying to set up webdriver test (with firefoxdriver) in hudson.

In my ant file, I start "vncserver :1" firstly and then start my test by passing

〈env key="DISPLAY" value=":1" /〉

to my test case.

I can run this in a terminal with sudo.  However when I start the job in hudson (running with root), I always got:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '2.6.18-128.1.14.el5a02xen', java.version: '1.6.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:92)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:71)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:85)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:121)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:77)
at amazon.dropship.selfservice.test.WebTesterImpl.(WebTesterImpl.java:38)
at amazon.dropship.selfservice.test.WebTesterImpl.getInstance(WebTesterImpl.java:48)
at amazon.dropship.selfservice.test.DSCentralTestBase.setUp(DSCentralTestBase.java:39)
at amazon.dropship.selfservice.test.smoke.ReadOnlyTests.setUp(ReadOnlyTests.java:11)

Comment: Are you using the selenium server at your hudson's machine?

Comment: Have you tried these Hudson plugin:

1.  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin

2.  http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Xvnc+Plugin

Might be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the environment variables:

- HOME =/root
- USER = root

That was all.  Thanks for looking at this